# Entity Framework function import is not refreshing changes

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I deleted a stored procedure from the database, then trying to update the entity framework model, and I see Stored procedure / functions have been updated, but the function imports didn't.

Below is the image explaining the problem

[image]

Currently, I am doing this way:

```
1. Delete the stored procedure from database
2. Run the EF update wizard
3. Go to Function Imports folder
4. Delete the stored procedure
5. Go to Complex Types
6. Delete the complex type
```

How to fix this ?

Comment: @user2012384 I usually go into the model browser, In main menu select View > Other Windows > Entity Data Model Browser (it usually opens in the same panel as Solution explorer), and delete the stored procedure that has changed, and re-add it back in.

Comment: Oh I see, such a weird design..